# What do the letters "a" and "s" mean in the context of this SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, syntax

```
$rank = $db->query("
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT a.*, @row:=@row+1 
AS `result` 
FROM users a, (SELECT @row:=0) s ORDER BY id ASC )
a 
WHERE id = '".$user_id."'
");
```

I found the following query on SO, and am trying to understand how it works. Nothing detailed was mentioned in the answer.

So far I understand everything except the single letters "a" and "s"

What do they mean?

Comment: Those are just alias.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php

Comment: @Ivan Petrov you can use it to fetch column value of that particular table like a.username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `s` here are aliases - shorter names used to reference the items in your `from` clause, for convenience sake.